# Installed XP service pack 3 and it messed the PC

Tags: windows-xp

Installed XP Service Pack 3 and it messed the PC. first I couldn't install it cause it was giving an error message saying;

Service Pack 3 set up cannot update a checked debug system with a free retail  version of service pack 3 or vice versa

I googled and found a solution which suggested to modify some registry key value and it installed. but windows didn't start properly. but I could access safe mode and I rolled back to a early system restore point. now few downloaded files are missing and firefox doesn't start.

1. If I restore to the point I installed service pack 3 and (*that
   restore point is available*) accessed to safe mode can I recover
   missing files?
2. And if I uninstall xp SP 3 from safe mode will I have to install
   service pack 2 again, will I get my files back?

Edited Key:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion
```

String "*CurrentType* " changed its value to *Checked* from *multiprocessor free*

[Solved] went back to the last restore point and everything solved but still I need that service pack 3 installed so badly. as it turned out the instalation pack I downloaded is meant for devs. where I can find the right pack. my XP is professional 5.1

Comment: Can you edit your question and put the registry key update you used?  You are not giving all the info.  Please provide specific data.  Do you have checked debug XP version?

Comment: Yes its a debug version

Comment: http://web.archive.org/web/20080725021245/http://download.microsoft.com/download/d/3/0/d30e32d8-418a-469d-b600-f32ce3edf42d/WindowsXP-KB936929-SP3-x86-ENU.exe